# How do i install perfect scrollbar in angular4/5

Tags: angular, angular5

I tried to install perfect-scrollbar(https://www.npmjs.com/package/perfect-scrollbar) in the following url in my angular app. But every time it gives me error like perfect scrollbar is not a function. The following steps i tried but nothing worked out. In my component after installed perfect scrollbar through npm,

```
import PerfectScrollbar from 'perfect-scrollbar';
const ps = new PerfectScrollbar('#container');
```

i added these codes in my component.But it gives error like perfectscrollbar is not a function. Please help if anyone knows.

Comment: Use [ngx-perfect-scrollbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-perfect-scrollbar), It's an angular wrapper for perfect-scroll-bar.

Comment: after installed this issue coming : (SystemJS) Cannot read property 'forRoot' of undefined.

Comment: @user2703151, have you solved the problem and Please post the solution if you find one.

Comment: no still the issue there

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
/deep/ {
   @import "~perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar";
}

:host {
   div {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }
}
```

COMPONENT:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import PerfectScrollbar from 'perfect-scrollbar';

@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: './...',
  styleUrls: ['./...']
})
export class MyComponent AfterViewInit {

  constructor() {}

  @ViewChild('demo') demo: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    new PerfectScrollbar(this.demo.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div #demo>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>b</p>
    <p>c</p>
    <p>d</p>
    <p>e</p>
    <p>f</p>
    <p>g</p>
    <p>h</p>
    <p>i</p>
    <p>j</p>
    <p>k</p>
    <p>l</p>
    <p>m</p>
    <p>n</p>
    <p>o</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>q</p>
    <p>r</p>
    <p>s</p>
    <p>t</p>
    <p>u</p>
    <p>v</p>
    <p>w</p>
    <p>x</p>
    <p>y</p>
    <p>z</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [ngx-perfect-scrollbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-perfect-scrollbar) and you can import it like this
installation

npm i ngx-perfect-scrollbar

and also install the dependencies [perfect-scrollbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/perfect-scrollbar)  and  [resize-observer-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resize-observer-polyfill)

in angular-cli.json

```
"scripts":[
"../node_modules/perfect-scrollbar/dist/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"
]
```

in App.module.ts

```
import { PerfectScrollbarModule, PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface,PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';
    const DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG: PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface = {
        suppressScrollX: true //only if u want to supress scrolling in x
      };
    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            PerfectScrollbarModule,
        ],
        providers:[
        {
                provide: PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG,
                useValue: DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG
        }
        ]
    })
```

and in your html file

```
<perfect-scrollbar class="container">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="content">
<!--the content-->
</div>
            </div>
        </perfect-scrollbar>
```

Update (if you are using Sysem.config.js)
in system.config.js

```
 map: {
      'ngx-perfect-scrollbar': 'npm:ngx-perfect-scrollbar',
      'perfect-scrollbar': 'npm:perfect-scrollbar'
    },
    packages: {
      'ngx-perfect-scrollbar': {
          defaultExtension: 'js',
          main: './dist/index.js'
      },
      'perfect-scrollbar': {
          defaultExtension: 'js',
          main:'./index.js'
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you your solution is nice but after installed i am having this error in console. PerfectScrollbar is not defined in zonejs. Scrollbar not coming.

Comment: I referred the perfect scrollbar path in system js error will gone. But this error coming perfect_scrollbar_1.default is not a constructor

Comment: what is the version of perfect-scrollbar and ngx-perfect-scrollbar